# customizing the_password_form filter

Tags: theme-development, filters, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to customize the_password_form to integrate it with bootstrap inline-forms with an add_filter() function:

```
function custom_passowrd_form ( $form ) {
global $post;
$label = 'pwbox-'.( empty( $post->ID ) ? rand() : $post->ID );
$form = 
    '<p>' .
        __( "To view this protected post, enter the password below:" ) .
    '</p>' .
    '<form class="form-inline" action="' .
    esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=postpass',
                      'login_post' ) ) .
    '" method="post">' .
        '<div class="form-group"> ' .
            '<label class="sr-only" for="' .
            $label .
            '">' .
                __('Password') .
            ' :</label>' .
            '<input placeholder="'.
            __('Password') .
            '" class="form-control" name="post_password" id="' .
            $label .
            '" type="password" size="20" maxlength="20" />'.
        '</div>' .
        '<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="Submit" value="' .
            esc_attr__( "Submit" ) . '" />' .
    '</form>';
return $form;
}
if (! is_admin()) {
    add_filter('the_password_form','custom_passowrd_form');
}
```

everything is fine but the problem is the an extra `<p>` tag that wraps the submit button, here is the output:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="http://127.0.0.1/wp-login.php?action=postpass" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="pwbox-27">
            Password :
        </label>
        <input placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="post_password" id="pwbox-27" type="password" size="20" maxlength="20">
    </div>
    <p>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output from the password form is filtered through the `the_content` filter when you call `the_content()` in your template.

That means it also goes through the `wpautop()` function that wraps `<p></p>` around your submit button with this code:

```
// Rebuild the content as a string, wrapping every bit with a <p>.
foreach ( $pees as $tinkle ) {
        $pee .= '<p>' . trim($tinkle, "\n") . "</p>\n";
}
```

You can move your submit button inside your `<div></div>` part or try to remove the `wpautotop` filtering only when the password form is displayed.

Another approach would be to remove the `<p></p>` tags around your input elements:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content )
{
    // Check if we have an input element in the content
    if( false !== strpos( $content, '<input ' ) )
        $content = preg_replace('|<p>\s*(<input[^>]+/?>)\s*</p>|', "$1", $content );
    return $content;
}, 11 );
```

where we use a priority later than 10.

Comment: I don't get the point why the output of the password form should go through the wpautop() function

Comment: I don't know if it's a design decision, at least it's easier to implement than the alternative ;-) @samix73